# How to treat age-eligibility thresholds in household surveys (e.g. HRS)?

Tags: sampling, survey, survey-sampling, survey-weights

Most household surveys have age-eligibility thresholds. The HRS interviews individuals aged 51 and older, plus their spouse (if any) using PPS sampling.

Do I need to drop individuals who are younger than 51 (the spouses) for the study to be representative of the older population? How should I treat these cases?

Most often, papers simply drop observations (not individuals) if the respective age is lower than the threshold. However, does this not make the sample unrepresentative? Should we only use the primary respondent in the sample?

Comment: If you are sampling from a population of people aged 51+ and are only interested in individuals as such, then there is no need to interview the spouses (whatever age they are).  The primary purpose of interviewing the spouses is to get information about the household the individuals live in.  You might decide to add the spouses to the sample of individuals (at least if they are old enough) for convenience but you then need to reweight your results to avoid oversampling married people.

Comment: @Henry In the HRS, spouses receive their own ID and are thus enter the sample just like main respondents. In standard analyses, researchers always seem to use spouses as additional individuals in the sample (without treating them differently). Therefore, by default, spouses are part of the "main" sample, and do not have to be added separately.

Answer (score 0):

The consideration of those who are under the age threshold in household surveys such as the Health and Retirement Study (HRS) is contingent upon the particular research objectives and the population under investigation. People under the age of 51 would not be in the target population and should be removed from the analysis if the purpose of the study is to examine characteristics or outcomes only for those who are 51 years of age or older. As long as the study is structured to capture the features of the older population, then this exclusion usually wouldn't render the sample unrepresentative of that demographic.

Even if one spouse is younger than the cutoff, spousal data may still be crucial if the study's goal is to comprehend the dynamics of homes or couples. In these situations, the younger spouses are included because they offer pertinent details about the home or dyadic interactions and aid in comprehending the background of the older spouse.

When concentrating on the senior population, only data from those who satisfy the age requirements (51 and over) should be used. When examining family dynamics, incorporate information from both partners, irrespective of age, and employ suitable statistical techniques (eg weighting, stratification, matching, regression adjustment, mixed effects models or sensitivity analysis, where appropriate), to help guarantee that the younger persons do not distort the outcomes for the elderly demographic.

Comment: In the HRS, some spouses are younger than 51, but some reach the age-eligibility threshold in later years of the panel as they age. In this case, should the individuals be included or excluded? 
I know that this detail probably does not substantially affect the results of most studies, but I would like to understand what is "correct" from a statistical perspective.

If it helps, suppose we want to study how the onset of a chronic disease affects labor market outcomes. Note that my question is (in my view) not dependent on the research setting, but instead on the statistical "validity".

Comment: Both approaches can be statistically valid, but they might yield different insights. It's important to clearly articulate the rationale for the chosen method and to consider conducting additional analyses to check the robustness of your findings. Sensitivity analysis would be a good idea. There are quite a few issues to consider (eg age-period-cohort effects and longitudinal consistency) so I would recommend asking a new question about this.